# What is the relation between Purebred and non-Purebred crawlers?

Tags: angel-n-devil

On the show *Angel 'N' Devil*, there are several types of vampiric entities: Nightcrawlers and Daycrawlers, which are spiritual creatures that possess humans; and Purebred Nightcrawlers and Daycrawlers, which are essentially human-looking with a taste for blood. Both have powers like Energy Users.

The names, although translated, suggest a connection between the two groups. In addition, we know that the Purebred Nightcrawlers and Purebred Daycrawlers, if they die with malice in their hearts, will lose their physical form and turn into a "seed" that can possess people physically and looks like that of any other Crawler.

One obvious hypothesis is that regular Nightcrawlers and Daycrawlers are the seeds of long-dead Purebred Crawlers; the obvious counter to this hypothesis is that all Purebred Crawlers shown on the show are much stronger than the garden-variety Crawlers. Another is that the "Purebred" implies that the common Crawlers are descended from Purebreds and some other group, but of course, even if Purebred Daycrawlers and Nightcrawlers can have children with humans, they'd be physical, not disembodied.

Thus, what is the connection between Purebred and regular Crawlers?